# How to get user location city without using geo location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i find location of a user and its places nearby like it is done in facebook status box. Facebook does not seem to use geolocation as there is no GPS symbol in the browser which usually appears at the right end of the address box when geolocation is used.

Example of geolocation

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the IP of your user and then use some site api to get the location,
Take a look at this:

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php